# clojure per thread binding not working for me

Tags: clojure

I was reading the clojure page on vars (here: https://clojure.org/reference/vars) which states that when a `var` is marked dynamic `binding` is thread local:

> By default Vars are static, but per-thread bindings for Vars defined with metadata mark them as dynamic can be established via the macro binding and within-thread they obey a stack discipline

And a bit later:

> Bindings created with binding cannot be seen by any other thread. Likewise, bindings created with binding can be assigned to, which provides a means for a nested context to communicate with code before it on the call stack. This capability is opt-in only by setting a metadata tag :dynamic to true as in the code block above.

So I decided to try this out:

```
(def ^:dynamic x 0)
(defn print-x [] (prn x))
(binding [x 100] @(future (print-x)))
```

And I expect to see `0` printed because future causes the operation to execute in a new thread, but the result I get is `100`. I also noticed that the `binding` documentation does not make any mention of thread local binding, whereas there's a `with-bindings` function (or macro) which does talk about thread local bindings and has an alternate (wonky, if you ask me) syntax for specifying bindings, but that doesn't do what I expect either.

Any ideas? I must be missing something obvious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `future` function will automatically convey its bindings to the remote thread. This happens with the `binding-conveyor-fn`, which is similar to [bound-fn](http://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/bound-fn) which you can use for the same purpose in your own code.